# Argument 'Ctrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

Buenas Tardes Comunidad, vengo con este error.

En mi Archivo **iedu-angular.js** tengo lo siguiente:

```
angular.module('facturasiModulo', [])
.controller('IEDUCtrl', ['$scope', IEDUCtrl]);

function IEDUCtrl($scope){
  console.log("Aqui aun vivo");
  $scope.nivelEducativo = ["Prescolar", "Primaria", "Secundaria","Profesional Tecnico", "Bachillerato o su Equivalente"];
  $scope.currentNivelEducativo = "Prescolar";
  console.log("Termina tu JavaScrpit");
}
```

Y lo mando a llamar a mi **iedu.html.haml** de esta manera:

```
%div#iedu(ng-controller="IEDUCtrl")
```

Cuando cargo la pagina me aparece el siguiente error en la consola de JavaScript:

> Argument 'IEDUCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Saludos

Comment: si inspeaccionas el html generado (usa las developer tools del browser) en base al template, puedes validar que tienes al tributo ng-app y el ng-controller asignado correctamente ? Puedes validar que el tag script define el .js donde defines el controller

Comment: En el archivo angular.min.js viene esto:                                            AngularJS v1.0.5
(c) 2010-2012 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
License: MIT

Comment: No evaluaste actualizar la version de angular ?, recomendaria que al menos uses la 1.3, aunque actualmente esta la 1.5

Comment: Es un Proyecto ya grande, tengo que trabajar con las tecnologías que tiene, si actualizamos algo, se corre el riesgo de que fallen otros módulos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno gente, al parecer se resolvió mi problema de la siguiente manera,
tuve que agregar la siguiente linea de código:

```
//= require complementos/iedu_angular
```

En el archivo **applications.js** de mi proyecto.

Gracias a todos por su ayuda y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 1):

Asegura tener en tu `HAML`

```
%html{ ng:{ app:"miApplicacion",controller: "IEDUCtrl" } }
```

Comment: Lo curioso es que hay otras 5 funciones con la misma sintaxis pero diferente nombre, las cuales no están agregadas en el layout que tu mencionas pero estas si funcionan a la perfección.